# How to set httponly-cookie in react production without chrome settings via Express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, google-chrome, setcookie, cookie-httponly

Chrome does not store the cookie we set on the server side unless the settings are set in Chrome. If the user has disabled the chrome browser setting for cookies. The authentication system I made with the http only cookie does not work for users, I do not know how to go about it. Can we get permission to set cookies from such users?

*require('cookie-parser') imported

```
res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true , sameSite:'None' , maxAge: 7 * 24 * 6 * 604800 });
```

Comment: What settings are set in chrome? What did you get in chrome?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. If the user has disabled the chrome browser setting for cookies. The authentication system I made with the http only cookie does not work for users, I do not know how to go about it. Can we get permission to set cookies from such users?